# How to export from wpdb to csv without including html tags in table?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having trouble setting up an export from my WordPress install to a CSV file. The data displays fine, but there are 8 rows of HTML displaying above it that I cannot get rid of no matter what I do.

Code as follows:

```
$filename = 'test-' . time() . '.csv';

$header_row = array(
    0 => 'field1',
    1 => 'field2',
    2 => 'field3',
    3 => 'field4',
);

$data_rows = array();

global $wpdb, $bp;
$users = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4 FROM `TESTTABLE`" );

foreach ( $users as $u ) {
    $row = array();
    $row[0] = $u->FIELD1;
    $row[1] = $u->FIELD2;
    $row[2] = $u->FIELD3;
    $row[3] = $u->FIELD4;

    $data_rows[] = $row;
}

ob_clean();

$fh = @fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );

//fprintf( $fh, chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) );

header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0' );
header( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
header( 'Content-type: text/csv' );
header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$filename}" );
header( 'Expires: 0' );
header( 'Pragma: public' );


fputcsv($fh, $header_row );

foreach ( $data_rows as $data_row ) {
    fputcsv( $fh, $data_row );
}

fclose( $fh );

echo "Complete";

die();

?>
```

Would be much appreciated if I could get a hand with this, as I can't seem to get this data to display without additional stuff up the top!

Comment: Just to be clear, we are talking about HTML code _before_ the CSV data you are outputting there, not HTML data contained in one of the column values _inside_ the CSV data, yes? I am guessing that's probably parts of your template then, maybe the general WP header contents. How exactly are you triggering the above code?

Comment: @CBroe It's being embedded by a PHP snippet plugin, and runs every time the page is loaded. The first eight rows are HTML tags, and are separate to the data that should be in the CSV file (eg. field1, field2 etc). The headers for those start at row 9 and the data continues as it should until the end of the file.

Comment: _"It's being embedded by a PHP snippet plugin"_ - that's probably part of the issue then. `ob_clean` will only work, if output buffering was explicitly started before at some point - no way of telling here, whether that was actually the case.

Comment: So would the ideal way to go about it be to add it inline into the HTML and then call the function on init?

Comment: Yeah, you can't use `header` after init., Since that's when headers are sent. You have to hook to init